# Estimate $P(X\ge2)$ using Markov inequality, for $X$ normal $N(1,1)$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X$ will be normal variable such that $Var X= EX = 1$.  Find estimation (using Markov inequality) on $P(X\ge 2)$.

**My approach** 
: In order to use Markov inequality $X$ must be non-negative.    In our task there is no such assumption.   Why  ?  And second thing: Why task tell about $VarX=1$ ?  For Markov inequality it is sufficient to know $EX$, look:
$$P(X\ge 2) \le \frac{EX}{2} = \frac12$$

Comment: "In our task there is no such assumption." Yes, and this means that you must imagine a way to use Markov nevertheless, that is, to consider nonnegative random variables related to X even if X itself is not nonnegative.

Comment: Some remarks. 1. If $X$ is $N(1,1)$ then its distribution is symmetric with respect to $1$ hence $P(X\geqslant x)\leqslant\frac12$ for every $x>1$, in particular $P(X\geqslant2)\leqslant\frac12$. 2. Without assuming a specific distribution, only that $E(X)=\mathrm{var}(X)=1$, the bound $\frac12$ is the best one can achieve, as the Bernoulli distribution uniform on $\{0,2\}$ shows. 3. I fail to understand why the exercise precises that $X$ is normal and then recommends to use general tools, valid for every (square integrable) distribution. (Yes, this is not a very good exercise...)

Comment: @Did Good point. My original answer is quite useless and I have improved my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$. That is, $Y = X - 1$. We have
$$
P(X \geq 2) = P(Y \geq 1) = \frac{P(|Y|\geq 1)}{2} \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[|Y|]}{2}\tag{$\clubsuit$} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2\pi}}
$$

Note that $|Y|$ follows [half-normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution) and its expectation is $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$.

Comment: Your previous solution was about:  $P(X\ge 2) \le P(|X|\ge 2)$ Yeah ?

Comment: @HaskellFun Yes. That leads to very loose (useless) bound.

Comment: Ok, thanks :) Tell me one thing else: from wha you know that $\frac{P(|Y|\ge 1)}{2}$ ?

Comment: @HaskellFun Because Markov inequality requires positiveness of the random variable, one way is to consider the absolute value of $Y$. In this case, $$P(|Y| \geq 1) = P(Y \geq 1) + P(Y \leq -1)$$ and $$P(Y \geq 1) = P(Y \leq -1)$$ because $\mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ is symmetric.

Comment: what are you saying? The result i have about Markov Inequality does not demand any thing like the random variable should be positive.

Comment: @bunny https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality I used this one and it requires non-negativeness.